# Bootstrap 3 Carousel not starting automatically

Tags: joomla-3.x, jquery, javascript, joomla-3.5, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having trouble getting my bootstrap 3 carousel to work. On the site it will automatically advance if you first click to advance a slide. I have disabled the pause on hover. I tested it on Code Pen and it works like a charm. I think it might be a conflict with the JS but I dont know where to start.

```
(function($){   
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();

        // Script to Activate the Carousel 
        $('.carousel').carousel({
            interval: 3000,
            pause: 'none'
        });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

[Code Pen Link](http://codepen.io/yoderman94/pen/vGMZJq)

Comment: Are you getting any console log errors? If so, please add them to your question.

Comment: not really, just jQuery is undefined, but its coming from Joomla's no conflict script.

Comment: Try removing `(function($){` and `})(jQuery);` then replacing `$(document).ready(function(){` with `jQuery(document).ready(function($){`

Comment: Still no luck, here is what I have: 
//jQuery noConflict from Joomla Script
    jQuery.noConflict();
    // (function($){
     jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     // $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();

      // Script to Activate the Carousel 
      $('.carousel').carousel({
             interval: 3000,
         pause: 'none'
         });
     });
    // })(jQuery);

Comment: How are you importing the script? And do you have multiple jQuery instances?

Comment: I load them via php via `$doc->addScript( )`

results:
`<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" defer="defer"></script>`
  `<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" defer="defer"></script>`
  `<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js" type="text/javascript" defer="defer"></script>`

So no other jQuery version are being loaded

Test Site Link: http://secure192.servconfig.com/~shine/

Comment: Don't import jQuery like this. Refer to the Joomla documentation on how to import it porperly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39768/discussion-between-chad-j-treadway-and-lodder).

Comment: Give me a buzz when you're in the chat

Comment: @Lodder I am available if you are.

Comment: Hey, I'm in the chat room

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will post the answer as a reference.

In the end this was due to multiple instances of jQuery being loaded. 1 via a CDN and the other from Joomla's core.

Once fixed, we also ensured `jQuery.noConflict();` was used directly after jQuery being loaded.